# SP2007, how can I search on only prefix of a document title?

Tags: search

I am using SP2007. I got results when I search on "23-1234121-02". But when I search on "13-003914" I dont get results. Can I configure SP to get also results when someone searching on the prefix of a document?

Answer (score 1):

You can't in 2007. Prefix matching was introduced in 2010. You can try using Search SQL syntax in 2007, but that is deprecated in 2010 and removed in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

In order to search on the title is to implement a keyword query with the Title managed property.  For example, to search the title for marketing documents, I would enter something like this.Title:"Marketing"